# Standalone creates an extra space with the option build

Tags: standalone

I want to import some files with the `standalone` package.
But when I use the `\includestandalone` command with the option `build` to recompile this file every time, some extra space are added before the import of my file.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % 
\usepackage{standalone} 

\begin{filecontents}{toto.tex}
\documentclass{standalone} 
\begin{document}
toto
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    When I call the standalone command with the option build there is an extra space in front of the input

    .\includestandalone[mode=build]{./toto}.

    while when I do not use the mode build there is no extra space

    .\includestandalone{./toto}.
\end{document}
```

I found nothing about this kind of issue. Is it some avoidable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the commands in standalone.sty, `\sa@setquote`, has a number of spurious spaces:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        %
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{filecontents}{toto.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
toto
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\def\sa@setquote{%
    \ifx\sa@build@quote\relax
    \expandafter\ifx\csname sa@convert@quote\endcsname\relax
    \begingroup
    \@tempswafalse
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pdftexbanner\endcsname\relax
        \@tempswatrue
    \else
    \def\MiKTeX{MiKTeX}%<---
    \@onelevel@sanitize\MiKTeX
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\testmiktex\expandafter##\expandafter1\MiKTeX##2\relax{%
            \ifx\empty##2\empty
                \@tempswafalse
            \else
                \@tempswatrue
            \fi
    }%<---
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\testmiktex\expandafter\pdftexbanner\MiKTeX\relax\relax
    \fi
    \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \if@tempswa
    \def\sa@build@quote{"}%<---
    \else
    \def\sa@build@quote{'}%<---
    \fi
    \else
    \let\sa@build@quote\sa@convert@quote
    \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    When I call the standalone command with the option build there is an extra space in front of the input


    .\includestandalone[mode=build]{./toto}.

    while when I do not use the mode build there is no extra space

    .\includestandalone{./toto}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think that the package will be patch in the future ? If yes, in a close future ? (Thanks anyway)

Comment: Well if you report the problem to the author, I would expect that he corrects it fairly fast.

Comment: OK, this is done. I will see.